# How to resolve Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:?

Tags: dependencies

Scenario:

I have an application built with gradle

In build.gradle

```
sourceCompatibility = '11'
```

In dockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:11

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Error while running build image:

```
(docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/gcp-training-01-303001/spring-boot-dockerapp .)
```

error :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-11 05:25:06.131 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exampleSubscriberConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/codersee/simplepubsub/config/ExampleSubscriberConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPublisherFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory]: Factory method 'defaultPublisherFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]

 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at com.codersee.simplepubsub.SimplePubsubApplication.main(SimplePubsubApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[simple-pubsub-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPublisherFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory]: Factory method 'defaultPublisherFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubPublisherTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPublisherFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory]: Factory method 'defaultPublisherFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPublisherFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory]: Factory method 'defaultPublisherFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory]: Factory method 'defaultPublisherFactory'threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:287) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.DefaultPublisherFactory.<init>(DefaultPublisherFactory.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.defaultPublisherFactory(GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.java:322) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb3b1674.CGLIB$defaultPublisherFactory$14(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb3b1674$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f811fc1d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb3b1674.defaultPublisherFactory(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1994) helps?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.Same errors still

Answer (score 0):

> *“java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The project ID can't be null or empty.”*

This error may be encountered even if project id is set in `Google Cloud`. However, setting project id again solves the problem (set the `Google Cloud` project id to the active `gcloud` configuration).

Install `gcloud-cli` if not already on your system and run the following command (`project-id` parameter can be obtained in the related `application.properties` file):

`gcloud config set project <project-id>`

for example:

`gcloud config set project demo-project-sandbox`

Link: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install